# Use VBA to get "background-color" value from HTML <td> tag for use in Excel

Tags: html, excel, vba

I have spent many hours researching how to get the color value from a  tag like the following:
[image from HTML page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukzvg.jpg)

I have retrieved the  tags as

Set tdItems = hTable.document.getElementsByTagName("td")

I have tried:

strStyle = tdItem.getAttribute("style") 'but that does not return the attribute values, simply the name of the attribute "background-color".

I tried: 
strStyle = tdItem.Style("Background-Color") 'fails to compile

I have been unable to find the right command to return just the background-color value. I am not interested in the other style attributes.  I am retrieving the tdItem.innertext values for the whole table successfully into a spreadsheet, but I'd like to grab the color coded into each HTML cell and use it in the spreadsheet.
Can anyone help?

Comment: What happens if you do something like `Debug.Print tdItem.Style`?

Comment: @Ryan: Thanks for you suggestion. Unfortunately it returns a blank value.

Comment: @Ryan: Correction:  When there is a value in the field, it returnS

Comment: @Ryan: Correction:  When there is a value in the field, it returns
"Style = BACKGROUND-COLOR" 
However I tried a couple of other things:
Debug.Print "Color = "; tdItem.Style.Color
returns  "Color = black"
But if I try   Debug.Print "Color = "; tdItem.Style.Background-Color VBA puts spaces around the hyphen. Is there a way to force the correct format of that attribute

Comment: Sounds like you want .Style.color. That returns the color property.

Comment: @Ryan:  No - .Style.color refers to the text color in the cell.  I want the back-ground color.  I tried to backslash the hypher ( \- )but that didn't work.  VBA automatically changes the string to:

Debug.Print "Color = "; tdItem.Style.Background - Color   ;notice the spaces around the hyphen.

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: @Ryan: Unfortunately not - its a confidential site.

Comment: In the end I may need to set color by values in the spreadsheet.  The problem is that sometimes empty cells have a fill-color I'd like to capture too.  BTW - If I do an interactive copy and paste from the HTML table into a spreadsheet, it works perfectly.  Doing it programmatically in VBA is my challenge!